# How to correctly select and show (or insert) data from (in) MySQL database with AJAX call to PHP function?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, function, jquery

So far I have something like this:

```
//HTML
<body onload=getRoomTemp();>

//JS
function getRoomTemp() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getRoomTemp.php",
    datatype: "text";
    data: {
        temp: temp
    }
}).done(function () { $('#getRoomTemp').append(text); });
}

//PHP
<?php
if (isset($_POST['temp'])) {
require('database.php');

$query = ("SELECT temp FROM tempWHERE tempID=1");

$res = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR ".__LINE__.": ".mysql_error());
while ($ar = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $temperatureIn = $ar['temp'];
    echo $temperatureIn;
    }
}
?>
```

So, when my HTML body loads, I would like to make query and show query result in div called "getRoomTemp" with AJAX. Later, I will need the same technique to insert data in MySQL (single number value) on button click.

I can't find the problem with my current code, tried different dataType for ajax but no success. Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 undefined identifiers `temp` and `text`, try

```
function getRoomTemp() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getRoomTemp.php",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
        temp: 'temp'
    }
  }).done(function (text) { $('#getRoomTemp').append(text); });
}
```

Comment: change `;` to `,` in front of `datatype` :)

Comment: Hm, thank you guys, I've done that, now nothing happens and Google Chrome's console said: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in jQuery library :(